# several wsl vms. How?

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On WIndows 11 I have an app named "Ubuntu"

When I launch it, a terminal will come up with an Ubuntu bash shell in it

Can I have 2 distinct installations of Ubuntu ?

How ?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9977

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 installed on the same machine.
You do not need to use PowerShell to install it (although I personally usually do).

***Go to the Microsoft Store and install the distros from there.***

If you don't have WSL already added, a "windows features" checkbox (again, no powershell needed) will install WSL.

[image]

If you search your start menu, you will find them both like this:

[image]